# Why does my Ubuntu 18.04 randomly suspend?

Tags: 18.04, suspend, restart

My Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS used to work just fine, however lately it started to suspend randomly. What happens after? At the beginning I could log in again, and everything was there unchanged. Now, it basicaly restarts. I get a message (the photo of the message can be found below), where it either gets stuck or I can log in (but it restarted). This has become more and more often, eve every 5 minutes. What could I do? I removed the suspend option from Settings → Power, but no improvement.

This is the message I get after it suspends:

[image: Photo of message which I get after the system suspends]

Output of `dmesg` (in case it can be of any help):

```
federico@lenovo:~$ dmesg

[    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x2f, date = 2019-02-17
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.4.0-42-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-023) (gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)) #46~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 07:21:24 UTC 2020 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-42.46~18.04.1-generic 5.4.44)
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic root=UUID=f490b95f-15df-462b-b5d5-f222638ec84d ro quiet splash vt.handoff=1
[    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
[    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
[    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
[    0.000000]   Hygon HygonGenuine
[    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
[    0.000000]   zhaoxin   Shanghai  
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 floating point registers'
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'SSE registers'
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x004: 'AVX registers'
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: xstate_offset[2]:  576, xstate_sizes[2]:  256
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: Enabled xstate features 0x7, context size is 832 bytes, using 'standard' format.
[    0.000000] BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009cfff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009d000-0x00000000000bffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000001fffffff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000020000000-0x00000000201fffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000020200000-0x000000003fffffff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000040000000-0x00000000401fffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000040200000-0x00000000c8b36fff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000c8b37000-0x00000000c8d38fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000c8d39000-0x00000000d7c9efff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000d7c9f000-0x00000000dae9efff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000dae9f000-0x00000000daf9efff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000daf9f000-0x00000000daffefff] ACPI data
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000dafff000-0x00000000daffffff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000db000000-0x00000000df9fffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000f80f8000-0x00000000f80f8fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed1c000-0x00000000fed1ffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000021f5fffff] usable
[    0.000000] NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
[    0.000000] e820: update [mem 0xc89fe018-0xc8a0e057] usable ==> usable
[    0.000000] e820: update [mem 0xc89fe018-0xc8a0e057] usable ==> usable
[    0.000000] extended physical RAM map:
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009cfff] usable
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x000000000009d000-0x00000000000bffff] reserved
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000001fffffff] usable
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000020000000-0x00000000201fffff] reserved
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000020200000-0x000000003fffffff] usable
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000040000000-0x00000000401fffff] reserved
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000040200000-0x00000000c89fe017] usable
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000c89fe018-0x00000000c8a0e057] usable
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000c8a0e058-0x00000000c8b36fff] usable
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000c8b37000-0x00000000c8d38fff] reserved
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000c8d39000-0x00000000d7c9efff] usable
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000d7c9f000-0x00000000dae9efff] reserved
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000dae9f000-0x00000000daf9efff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000daf9f000-0x00000000daffefff] ACPI data
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000dafff000-0x00000000daffffff] usable
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000db000000-0x00000000df9fffff] reserved
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000f80f8000-0x00000000f80f8fff] reserved
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000fed1c000-0x00000000fed1ffff] reserved
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000021f5fffff] usable
[    0.000000] efi: EFI v2.31 by Phoenix Technologies Ltd.
[    0.000000] efi:  ACPI 2.0=0xdaffe014  ACPI=0xdaffe000  SMBIOS=0xdae3b000 
[    0.000000] secureboot: Secure boot disabled
[    0.000000] SMBIOS 2.7 present.
[    0.000000] DMI: LENOVO 62742QG/62742QG, BIOS H5ET73WW(1.16) 04/10/2013
[    0.000000] tsc: Fast TSC calibration using PIT
[    0.000000] tsc: Detected 2294.661 MHz processor
[    0.000631] e820: update [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff] usable ==> reserved
[    0.000633] e820: remove [mem 0x000a0000-0x000fffff] usable
[    0.000640] last_pfn = 0x21f600 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
[    0.000645] MTRR default type: uncachable
[    0.000646] MTRR fixed ranges enabled:
[    0.000647]   00000-9FFFF write-back
[    0.000648]   A0000-FFFFF uncachable
[    0.000649] MTRR variable ranges enabled:
[    0.000651]   0 base 0FFC00000 mask FFFC00000 write-protect
[    0.000652]   1 base 000000000 mask F80000000 write-back
[    0.000653]   2 base 080000000 mask FC0000000 write-back
[    0.000654]   3 base 0C0000000 mask FE0000000 write-back
[    0.000655]   4 base 0DC000000 mask FFC000000 uncachable
[    0.000655]   5 base 0DB000000 mask FFF000000 uncachable
[    0.000656]   6 base 100000000 mask F00000000 write-back
[    0.000657]   7 base 200000000 mask FE0000000 write-back
[    0.000658]   8 base 21F800000 mask FFF800000 uncachable
[    0.000659]   9 base 21F600000 mask FFFE00000 uncachable
[    0.001583] x86/PAT: Configuration [0-7]: WB  WC  UC- UC  WB  WP  UC- WT  
[    0.001773] last_pfn = 0xdb000 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
[    0.023919] check: Scanning 1 areas for low memory corruption
[    0.023923] reserving inaccessible SNB gfx pages
[    0.023928] BRK [0x15c601000, 0x15c601fff] PGTABLE
[    0.023930] BRK [0x15c602000, 0x15c602fff] PGTABLE
[    0.023932] BRK [0x15c603000, 0x15c603fff] PGTABLE
[    0.023991] BRK [0x15c604000, 0x15c604fff] PGTABLE
[    0.023993] BRK [0x15c605000, 0x15c605fff] PGTABLE
[    0.024123] BRK [0x15c606000, 0x15c606fff] PGTABLE
[    0.024309] BRK [0x15c607000, 0x15c607fff] PGTABLE
[    0.024323] BRK [0x15c608000, 0x15c608fff] PGTABLE
[    0.024337] BRK [0x15c609000, 0x15c609fff] PGTABLE
[    0.024406] BRK [0x15c60a000, 0x15c60afff] PGTABLE
[    0.024499] BRK [0x15c60b000, 0x15c60bfff] PGTABLE
[    0.024634] BRK [0x15c60c000, 0x15c60cfff] PGTABLE
[    0.024901] secureboot: Secure boot disabled
[    0.024902] RAMDISK: [mem 0x3d91c000-0x3fffdfff]
[    0.024912] ACPI: Early table checksum verification disabled
[    0.024916] ACPI: RSDP 0x00000000DAFFE014 000024 (v02 LENOVO)
[    0.024919] ACPI: XSDT 0x00000000DAFFE170 0000A4 (v01 LENOVO TP-H5    00001160 PTL  00000002)
[    0.024925] ACPI: FACP 0x00000000DAFE9000 00010C (v05 LENOVO TP-H5    00001160 PTL  00000002)
[    0.024931] ACPI: DSDT 0x00000000DAFEB000 010AE0 (v01 LENOVO TP-H5    00001160 INTL 20061109)
[    0.024935] ACPI: FACS 0x00000000DAF7A000 000040
[    0.024938] ACPI: SLIC 0x00000000DAFFD000 000176 (v01 LENOVO TP-H5    00001160 PTL  00000001)
[    0.024941] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000DAFFC000 00052C (v01 LENOVO SataAhci 00001000 INTL 20061109)
[    0.024944] ACPI: ASF! 0x00000000DAFEA000 0000A5 (v32 LENOVO TP-H5    00001160 PTL  00000002)
[    0.024947] ACPI: HPET 0x00000000DAFE7000 000038 (v01 LENOVO TP-H5    00001160 PTL  00000002)
[    0.024951] ACPI: APIC 0x00000000DAFE6000 000098 (v01 LENOVO TP-H5    00001160 PTL  00000002)
[    0.024954] ACPI: MCFG 0x00000000DAFE5000 00003C (v01 LENOVO TP-H5    00001160 PTL  00000002)
[    0.024957] ACPI: FPDT 0x00000000DAFE4000 000064 (v01 LENOVO TP-H5    00001160 PTL  00000002)
[    0.024960] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000DAFE3000 0009AA (v01 PmRef  Cpu0Ist  00003000 INTL 20061109)
[    0.024963] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000DAFE2000 000A92 (v01 PmRef  CpuPm    00003000 INTL 20061109)
[    0.024967] ACPI: UEFI 0x00000000DAFE1000 00003E (v01 LENOVO TP-H5    00001160 PTL  00000002)
[    0.024970] ACPI: UEFI 0x00000000DAFE0000 000042 (v01 PTL    COMBUF   00000001 PTL  00000001)
[    0.024973] ACPI: MSDM 0x00000000DAF74000 000055 (v03 LENOVO TP-H5    00001160 PTL  00000002)
[    0.024976] ACPI: UEFI 0x00000000DAFDF000 0002BA (v01 LENOVO TP-H5    00001160 PTL  00000002)
[    0.024979] ACPI: DBG2 0x00000000DAFDE000 00002C (v00 LENOVO TP-H5    00001160 PTL  00000002)
[    0.024982] ACPI: BGRT 0x00000000DAFDD000 000038 (v00 LENOVO TP-H5    00001160 PTL  00000002)
[    0.024992] ACPI: Local APIC address 0xfee00000
[    0.025087] No NUMA configuration found
[    0.025088] Faking a node at [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000021f5fffff]
[    0.025099] NODE_DATA(0) allocated [mem 0x21f5d1000-0x21f5fbfff]
[    0.025367] Zone ranges:
[    0.025368]   DMA      [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x0000000000ffffff]
[    0.025369]   DMA32    [mem 0x0000000001000000-0x00000000ffffffff]
[    0.025370]   Normal   [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000021f5fffff]
[    0.025371]   Device   empty
[    0.025372] Movable zone start for each node
[    0.025376] Early memory node ranges
[    0.025377]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x000000000009cfff]
[    0.025378]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000001fffffff]
[    0.025379]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000020200000-0x000000003fffffff]
[    0.025379]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000040200000-0x00000000c8b36fff]
[    0.025380]   node   0: [mem 0x00000000c8d39000-0x00000000d7c9efff]
[    0.025381]   node   0: [mem 0x00000000dafff000-0x00000000daffffff]
[    0.025382]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000021f5fffff]
[    0.025781] Zeroed struct page in unavailable ranges: 37830 pages
[    0.025783] Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x000000021f5fffff]
[    0.025785] On node 0 totalpages: 2059322
[    0.025786]   DMA zone: 64 pages used for memmap
[    0.025787]   DMA zone: 156 pages reserved
[    0.025788]   DMA zone: 3996 pages, LIFO batch:0
[    0.025856]   DMA32 zone: 13723 pages used for memmap
[    0.025857]   DMA32 zone: 878238 pages, LIFO batch:63
[    0.040817]   Normal zone: 18392 pages used for memmap
[    0.040819]   Normal zone: 1177088 pages, LIFO batch:63
[    0.058604] Reserving Intel graphics memory at [mem 0xdba00000-0xdf9fffff]
[    0.058754] ACPI: PM-Timer IO Port: 0x408
[    0.058757] ACPI: Local APIC address 0xfee00000
[    0.058766] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x00] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.058767] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x01] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.058779] IOAPIC[0]: apic_id 2, version 32, address 0xfec00000, GSI 0-23
[    0.058781] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 0 global_irq 2 dfl dfl)
[    0.058782] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 9 global_irq 9 high level)
[    0.058784] ACPI: IRQ0 used by override.
[    0.058785] ACPI: IRQ9 used by override.
[    0.058787] Using ACPI (MADT) for SMP configuration information
[    0.058789] ACPI: HPET id: 0x8086a301 base: 0xfed00000
[    0.058801] e820: update [mem 0xccc4a000-0xcccc5fff] usable ==> reserved
[    0.058811] smpboot: Allowing 8 CPUs, 4 hotplug CPUs
[    0.058834] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff]
[    0.058836] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x0009d000-0x000bffff]
[    0.058837] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x000c0000-0x000fffff]
[    0.058838] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x20000000-0x201fffff]
[    0.058840] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x40000000-0x401fffff]
[    0.058842] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xc89fe000-0xc89fefff]
[    0.058843] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xc8a0e000-0xc8a0efff]
[    0.058845] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xc8b37000-0xc8d38fff]
[    0.058847] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xccc4a000-0xcccc5fff]
[    0.058849] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xd7c9f000-0xdae9efff]
[    0.058850] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xdae9f000-0xdaf9efff]
[    0.058850] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xdaf9f000-0xdaffefff]
[    0.058852] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xdb000000-0xdf9fffff]
[    0.058853] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xdfa00000-0xf80f7fff]
[    0.058853] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xf80f8000-0xf80f8fff]
[    0.058854] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xf80f9000-0xfed1bfff]
[    0.058855] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfed1c000-0xfed1ffff]
[    0.058855] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfed20000-0xffffffff]
[    0.058857] [mem 0xdfa00000-0xf80f7fff] available for PCI devices
[    0.058858] Booting paravirtualized kernel on bare hardware
[    0.058862] clocksource: refined-jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 7645519600211568 ns
[    0.058869] setup_percpu: NR_CPUS:8192 nr_cpumask_bits:8 nr_cpu_ids:8 nr_node_ids:1
[    0.059110] percpu: Embedded 54 pages/cpu s184320 r8192 d28672 u262144
[    0.059119] pcpu-alloc: s184320 r8192 d28672 u262144 alloc=1*2097152
[    0.059120] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
[    0.059156] Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 2026987
[    0.059157] Policy zone: Normal
[    0.059158] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic root=UUID=f490b95f-15df-462b-b5d5-f222638ec84d ro quiet splash vt.handoff=1
[    0.059792] Dentry cache hash table entries: 1048576 (order: 11, 8388608 bytes, linear)
[    0.060053] Inode-cache hash table entries: 524288 (order: 10, 4194304 bytes, linear)
[    0.060156] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:on, heap free:off
[    0.064067] Calgary: detecting Calgary via BIOS EBDA area
[    0.064069] Calgary: Unable to locate Rio Grande table in EBDA - bailing!
[    0.087657] Memory: 7888032K/8237288K available (14339K kernel code, 2378K rwdata, 4924K rodata, 2704K init, 5020K bss, 349256K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
[    0.087664] random: get_random_u64 called from __kmem_cache_create+0x41/0x550 with crng_init=0
[    0.087824] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=8, Nodes=1
[    0.087837] Kernel/User page tables isolation: enabled
[    0.087854] ftrace: allocating 44191 entries in 173 pages
[    0.108728] rcu: Hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.108730] rcu:     RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=8192 to nr_cpu_ids=8.
[    0.108731]  Tasks RCU enabled.
[    0.108732] rcu: RCU calculated value of scheduler-enlistment delay is 25 jiffies.
[    0.108733] rcu: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=16, nr_cpu_ids=8
[    0.112094] NR_IRQS: 524544, nr_irqs: 488, preallocated irqs: 16
[    0.112349] vt handoff: transparent VT on vt#1
[    0.112357] Console: colour dummy device 80x25
[    0.112363] printk: console [tty0] enabled
[    0.112382] ACPI: Core revision 20190816
[    0.112548] clocksource: hpet: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 133484882848 ns
[    0.112565] APIC: Switch to symmetric I/O mode setup
[    0.112637] x2apic: IRQ remapping doesn't support X2APIC mode
[    0.113086] ..TIMER: vector=0x30 apic1=0 pin1=2 apic2=-1 pin2=-1
[    0.132566] clocksource: tsc-early: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x2113818f8d0, max_idle_ns: 440795268035 ns
[    0.132570] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 4589.32 BogoMIPS (lpj=9178644)
[    0.132572] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.138959] LSM: Security Framework initializing
[    0.138974] Yama: becoming mindful.
[    0.139018] AppArmor: AppArmor initialized
[    0.139070] Mount-cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
[    0.139084] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
[    0.139102] *** VALIDATE tmpfs ***
[    0.139272] *** VALIDATE proc ***
[    0.139336] *** VALIDATE cgroup1 ***
[    0.139338] *** VALIDATE cgroup2 ***
[    0.139392] mce: CPU0: Thermal monitoring enabled (TM1)
[    0.139402] process: using mwait in idle threads
[    0.139405] Last level iTLB entries: 4KB 512, 2MB 8, 4MB 8
[    0.139406] Last level dTLB entries: 4KB 512, 2MB 32, 4MB 32, 1GB 0
[    0.139410] Spectre V1 : Mitigation: usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
[    0.139412] Spectre V2 : Mitigation: Full generic retpoline
[    0.139412] Spectre V2 : Spectre v2 / SpectreRSB mitigation: Filling RSB on context switch
[    0.139413] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.139415] Spectre V2 : mitigation: Enabling conditional Indirect Branch Prediction Barrier
[    0.139415] Spectre V2 : User space: Mitigation: STIBP via seccomp and prctl
[    0.139417] Speculative Store Bypass: Mitigation: Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp
[    0.139420] MDS: Mitigation: Clear CPU buffers
[    0.139590] Freeing SMP alternatives memory: 40K
[    0.142445] smpboot: CPU0: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2348M CPU @ 2.30GHz (family: 0x6, model: 0x2a, stepping: 0x7)
[    0.142563] Performance Events: PEBS fmt1+, SandyBridge events, 16-deep LBR, full-width counters, Intel PMU driver.
[    0.142571] ... version:                3
[    0.142571] ... bit width:              48
[    0.142572] ... generic registers:      4
[    0.142573] ... value mask:             0000ffffffffffff
[    0.142573] ... max period:             00007fffffffffff
[    0.142574] ... fixed-purpose events:   3
[    0.142575] ... event mask:             000000070000000f
[    0.142617] rcu: Hierarchical SRCU implementation.
[    0.143858] NMI watchdog: Enabled. Permanently consumes one hw-PMU counter.
[    0.143959] smp: Bringing up secondary CPUs ...
[    0.144078] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[    0.144079] .... node  #0, CPUs:      #1
[    0.144674] MDS CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/mds.html for more details.
[    0.144749]  #2 #3
[    0.150988] smp: Brought up 1 node, 4 CPUs
[    0.150988] smpboot: Max logical packages: 2
[    0.150988] smpboot: Total of 4 processors activated (18357.28 BogoMIPS)
[    0.152924] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.152924] x86/mm: Memory block size: 128MB
[    0.153549] PM: Registering ACPI NVS region [mem 0xdae9f000-0xdaf9efff] (1048576 bytes)
[    0.153549] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 7645041785100000 ns
[    0.153549] futex hash table entries: 2048 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
[    0.153549] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    0.153549] PM: RTC time: 09:19:23, date: 2020-10-29
[    0.153549] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.153549] audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)
[    0.153549] audit: type=2000 audit(1603963163.040:1): state=initialized audit_enabled=0 res=1
[    0.153549] EISA bus registered
[    0.153549] cpuidle: using governor ladder
[    0.153549] cpuidle: using governor menu
[    0.153549] ACPI FADT declares the system doesn't support PCIe ASPM, so disable it
[    0.153549] ACPI: bus type PCI registered
[    0.153549] acpiphp: ACPI Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.5
[    0.153549] PCI: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-3f] at [mem 0xf8000000-0xfbffffff] (base 0xf8000000)
[    0.153549] PCI: not using MMCONFIG
[    0.153549] PCI: Using configuration type 1 for base access
[    0.153549] core: PMU erratum BJ122, BV98, HSD29 worked around, HT is on
[    0.153549] ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: Set to 'normal', was 'performance'
[    0.157212] HugeTLB registered 2.00 MiB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
[    0.157212] ACPI: Added _OSI(Module Device)
[    0.157212] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Device)
[    0.157212] ACPI: Added _OSI(3.0 _SCP Extensions)
[    0.157212] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Aggregator Device)
[    0.157212] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Dell-Video)
[    0.157212] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
[    0.157212] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-HPI-Hybrid-Graphics)
[    0.177682] ACPI: 4 ACPI AML tables successfully acquired and loaded
[    0.179744] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.180862] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.180870] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF8EA21591F000 00083B (v01 PmRef  Cpu0Cst  00003001 INTL 20061109)
[    0.182257] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.182263] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF8EA215A45C00 000303 (v01 PmRef  ApIst    00003000 INTL 20061109)
[    0.183376] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.183381] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF8EA215A8EC00 000119 (v01 PmRef  ApCst    00003000 INTL 20061109)
[    0.185605] ACPI: EC: EC started
[    0.185606] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
[    0.617911] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC: Used as first EC
[    0.617914] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC: GPE=0x17, EC_CMD/EC_SC=0x66, EC_DATA=0x62
[    0.617915] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC: Boot DSDT EC used to handle transactions
[    0.617916] ACPI: Interpreter enabled
[    0.617947] ACPI: (supports S0 S3 S4 S5)
[    0.617948] ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing
[    0.617991] PCI: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-3f] at [mem 0xf8000000-0xfbffffff] (base 0xf8000000)
[    0.619025] PCI: MMCONFIG at [mem 0xf8000000-0xfbffffff] reserved in ACPI motherboard resources
[    0.619037] PCI: Using host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=nocrs" and report a bug
[    0.619546] ACPI: Enabled 7 GPEs in block 00 to 3F
[    0.620976] ACPI: Power Resource [PUBS] (off)
[    0.630962] ACPI: PCI Root Bridge [PCI0] (domain 0000 [bus 00-3e])
[    0.630969] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI HPX-Type3]
[    0.631224] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC failed (AE_ERROR); disabling ASPM
[    0.631768] PCI host bridge to bus 0000:00
[    0.631771] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [io  0x0000-0x0cf7 window]
[    0.631772] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [io  0x0d00-0xffff window]
[    0.631774] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x000a0000-0x000bffff window]
[    0.631775] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x000c0000-0x000c3fff window]
[    0.631776] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x000c4000-0x000c7fff window]
[    0.631777] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x000c8000-0x000cbfff window]
[    0.631778] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x000cc000-0x000cffff window]
[    0.631780] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x000d0000-0x000d3fff window]
[    0.631781] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x000d4000-0x000d7fff window]
[    0.631782] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x000d8000-0x000dbfff window]
[    0.631783] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x000dc000-0x000dffff window]
[    0.631784] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x000e0000-0x000e3fff window]
[    0.631785] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x000e4000-0x000e7fff window]
[    0.631788] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x000e8000-0x000ebfff window]
[    0.631790] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x000ec000-0x000effff window]
[    0.631791] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x000f0000-0x000fffff window]
[    0.631792] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0xdfa00000-0xfeafffff window]
[    0.631794] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [bus 00-3e]
[    0.631805] pci 0000:00:00.0: [8086:0104] type 00 class 0x060000
[    0.631925] pci 0000:00:02.0: [8086:0116] type 00 class 0x030000
[    0.631936] pci 0000:00:02.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xf0000000-0xf03fffff 64bit]
[    0.631942] pci 0000:00:02.0: reg 0x18: [mem 0xe0000000-0xefffffff 64bit pref]
[    0.631946] pci 0000:00:02.0: reg 0x20: [io  0x3000-0x303f]
[    0.631959] pci 0000:00:02.0: BAR 2: assigned to efifb
[    0.632093] pci 0000:00:14.0: [8086:1e31] type 00 class 0x0c0330
[    0.632119] pci 0000:00:14.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xf0600000-0xf060ffff 64bit]
[    0.632194] pci 0000:00:14.0: PME# supported from D3hot D3cold
[    0.632312] pci 0000:00:16.0: [8086:1e3a] type 00 class 0x078000
[    0.632338] pci 0000:00:16.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xf0615000-0xf061500f 64bit]
[    0.632417] pci 0000:00:16.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.632529] pci 0000:00:1a.0: [8086:1e2d] type 00 class 0x0c0320
[    0.632553] pci 0000:00:1a.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xf061a000-0xf061a3ff]
[    0.632644] pci 0000:00:1a.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.632765] pci 0000:00:1b.0: [8086:1e20] type 00 class 0x040300
[    0.632788] pci 0000:00:1b.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xf0610000-0xf0613fff 64bit]
[    0.632871] pci 0000:00:1b.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.632988] pci 0000:00:1c.0: [8086:1e10] type 01 class 0x060400
[    0.633086] pci 0000:00:1c.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.633211] pci 0000:00:1c.1: [8086:1e12] type 01 class 0x060400
[    0.633313] pci 0000:00:1c.1: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.633438] pci 0000:00:1c.3: [8086:1e16] type 01 class 0x060400
[    0.633533] pci 0000:00:1c.3: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.633661] pci 0000:00:1d.0: [8086:1e26] type 00 class 0x0c0320
[    0.633684] pci 0000:00:1d.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xf0619000-0xf06193ff]
[    0.633774] pci 0000:00:1d.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.633892] pci 0000:00:1f.0: [8086:1e57] type 00 class 0x060100
[    0.634110] pci 0000:00:1f.2: [8086:1e03] type 00 class 0x010601
[    0.634130] pci 0000:00:1f.2: reg 0x10: [io  0x3088-0x308f]
[    0.634138] pci 0000:00:1f.2: reg 0x14: [io  0x309c-0x309f]
[    0.634146] pci 0000:00:1f.2: reg 0x18: [io  0x3080-0x3087]
[    0.634154] pci 0000:00:1f.2: reg 0x1c: [io  0x3098-0x309b]
[    0.634162] pci 0000:00:1f.2: reg 0x20: [io  0x3060-0x307f]
[    0.634170] pci 0000:00:1f.2: reg 0x24: [mem 0xf0618000-0xf06187ff]
[    0.634216] pci 0000:00:1f.2: PME# supported from D3hot
[    0.634329] pci 0000:00:1f.3: [8086:1e22] type 00 class 0x0c0500
[    0.634349] pci 0000:00:1f.3: reg 0x10: [mem 0xf0614000-0xf06140ff 64bit]
[    0.634371] pci 0000:00:1f.3: reg 0x20: [io  0xefa0-0xefbf]
[    0.634549] pci 0000:00:1c.0: PCI bridge to [bus 01]
[    0.634671] pci 0000:02:00.0: [14e4:4365] type 00 class 0x028000
[    0.634747] pci 0000:02:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xf0500000-0xf0507fff 64bit]
[    0.634879] pci 0000:02:00.0: enabling Extended Tags
[    0.635054] pci 0000:02:00.0: supports D1 D2
[    0.635055] pci 0000:02:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.635272] pci 0000:00:1c.1: PCI bridge to [bus 02]
[    0.635278] pci 0000:00:1c.1:   bridge window [mem 0xf0500000-0xf05fffff]
[    0.635362] pci 0000:03:00.0: [10ec:8168] type 00 class 0x020000
[    0.635398] pci 0000:03:00.0: reg 0x10: [io  0x2000-0x20ff]
[    0.635433] pci 0000:03:00.0: reg 0x18: [mem 0xf0404000-0xf0404fff 64bit pref]
[    0.635455] pci 0000:03:00.0: reg 0x20: [mem 0xf0400000-0xf0403fff 64bit pref]
[    0.635582] pci 0000:03:00.0: supports D1 D2
[    0.635583] pci 0000:03:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
[    0.635734] pci 0000:00:1c.3: PCI bridge to [bus 03]
[    0.635738] pci 0000:00:1c.3:   bridge window [io  0x2000-0x2fff]
[    0.635746] pci 0000:00:1c.3:   bridge window [mem 0xf0400000-0xf04fffff 64bit pref]
[    0.636770] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKA] (IRQs 1 3 4 5 6 10 11 12 14 15) *0, disabled.
[    0.636862] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKB] (IRQs 1 3 4 5 6 10 11 12 14 15) *0, disabled.
[    0.636951] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKC] (IRQs 1 3 4 5 6 10 11 12 14 15) *0, disabled.
[    0.637040] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKD] (IRQs 1 3 4 5 6 10 11 12 14 15) *0, disabled.
```

I can also post `cat /var/log/syslog`. I am not an advanced Ubuntu user.

Answer (score 0):

My previous laptop had similar issues. It would reboot on its own randomly.

Searching on the internet, I came across many possible reasons for this: faulty RAM, overheating GPU, overheating CPU, faulty disk, a faulty motherboard. So, yeah, it could be anything.

You can, however, try to catch the problem by the process of elimination:

1. First, check if it's a faulty disk. Try using your laptop with another disk or a linux live USB stick. If it happens again, then it's not a disk issue.
2. Second, check if it's a faulty RAM. Search about testing RAM using `memtest` from the BIOS. If it's a faulty RAM, you'll need to replace it.
3. Check if the shutdown was caused by overheating CPU. See this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/502794/162050. If so, disassemble your laptop to check if there's dust blocking fan's vents. You can also try replacing the thermal paste on your CPU and GPU. In some laptops, GPUs have a thermal pad instead of thermal paste. In that case, don't remove that pad.

If none of these things fix the issue, you should take it to a professional repair technician.

---

Talking about my old laptop with similar issues, one day it just died. On turning it on, it showed some random gibberish text on a black screen and would just hang there forever.

My advice would be to back up your data as soon as possible because such abrupt shutdowns may corrupt your whole disk. Take it to a professional repair technician. It might be a good idea to start looking for a new laptop.

Comment: I tried the 3 options, and all seems to be fine: 1) I checked the Disk, and the overall assessment says it is OK. 2) I tested the RAM, and seems ok. 3) I checked the temperature, and it seems to be ok. I shall take it to a professional repair technician, and start looking for a new one. If there any more ideas of actions I could try to fix the problem, or at least understands where it comes from, it would be most welcome. Thanks!